# Having issue with cin function in a loop

Tags: c++, loops, cin

I'm an just trying to fill an array with strings using a loop.  My problem is that when it enters the loop to input names it will instantaneously input a blank line for the first slot in the vector.  Why does this happen?  And how can I fix it.  Please don't mind my lack of code style, I'm a noob trying to regain my knowledge of programming before I start in a class this winter...

Here's some sample output:

```
How many people are in your family?
4
Please enter the names of all of your family members
check name:
Please enter the names of all of your family members
Matt
check name:Matt
Please enter the names of all of your family members
Evan
check name:Evan
Please enter the names of all of your family members
Michelle
check name:Michelle

Matt
Evan
Michelle
```

and this is my code:

```
vector<string> Names;
bool complete=0;
while(!complete)
{
    int number;
    cout << "How many people are in your family?" << endl;
    cin >> number;

    for(int i=0; i<number; i++)
    {
        string names;
        cin.clear();
        cout << "Please enter the names of all of your family members" << endl;
        getline(cin,names);
        Names.push_back(names);
        cout << "check name:" << names << endl;
    }
    complete = 1;
}

for (int i=0; i< Names.size(); i++)
{
    cout << Names[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Pick [one of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+getline+skipping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest you try

```
std::cin >> names;
```

instead of

```
getline(std::cin, names);
```

getline takes in `std::endl` or the  `\n` from your `std::cout` print string.  The idea is that getline will read until the `\n` character (which is an indication of an endline), but it will also consume the endline character.  This is why it is consuming the newline character into your vector.

Consider doing this . . .

```
std::cin.get();
```

which will read `std::endl` character and then use the getline function.

Comment: I wanted to use the getline function so that you could type full names both first and last.  But yeah that's exactly what was happening.

Comment: i forgot, i usually use `std::cin.get()` to discard the newline character when i use getline after a newline character.

Comment: That changes the semantics of the program. When someone enters a name that consists of a first name and a last name separated by a space, the original version treats both parts as one name. The suggested version treats them as two names.

Comment: Are you talking about cin?  Well I also suggested get before getline which I assume the Evan used.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you see this behavior is mixing the `>>` reads with getline. When you read the count, the input pointer is advanced to the end of the numeric input, i.e. 4, and stops right before the new line character is read.

This is when you call `getline`; the new line character is read, and the new line is returned right away.

To fix this problem, add a call to `getline` right after the `cin >> number` call, and discard the result.

Comment: Brillant!  Thanks so much.  I thought that maybe you would be able to clear whatever was in the cin function (in this case the new line) by using the cin.clear() command?!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mixing fonatted input (`std::cin >> number`) with unformatted input (`std::getline(std::cin, names)`). The formatted input stops at first non-integer character, most likely the newline you entered after the count. The easiest fix is to skip leading whitespace explicitly:

```
std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, names);
```

Note, that you also need to check after each input that it was successful:

```
if (std::cin >> number) {
    // do something after a successful read
}
```